# A way to handle common behaviors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I have multiple resources that *almost* have the same behavior. That is, those *almost* have same model, controller and view codes and same database table columns definition.

So I would like to find a way to DRY those resources. I already implemented modules and mixins for those in order to share part of the code (as validation methods, callbacks, view files but *not* controller files that, anyway, have very similar code).

Now, how can I do to handle this common behavior? Should I use something that Ruby on Rails developers named as `acts_as_something`? What do you advice about?

Comment: I think you should give us more details regarding this *almostness*

Comment: @Tudor Constantin - What details do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already did that, just name a method in your modules act_as_your_module_name and make sure your module extends from your Base Class, e.g. ActiveRecord::Base.extend act_as_your_module_name

http://www.cowboycoded.com/tag/acts_as/

Comment: Podolski - Thanks... now I have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557305/validation-methods-running-in-plugins