# Validation methods in plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, plugins

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I am trying to implement an `act_as_article` plugin for my application. What I would to do is run *validation* methods for the "acting as article class" inside that plugin (note: my plugin requires to create some database table columns in order to work - one of these is represented by the `title` attribute).

In my RoR application I have this code:

```
# vendor/plugins/article/lib/acts_as_article.rb
module Article
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validates :title,  # Validation method
      :presence => true
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def acts_as_article
      send :include, InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    ...
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Article


# app/models/review.rb
class Review
  acts_as_article

  ...
end
```

Using the above code the plugin works. However if I add some *Record Association* in the `Review` class like this:

```
class Review
  acts_as_article

  has_many :comments # Adding association

  ...
end
```

and in my `ReviewsController` I add the following, as well:

```
def create
  ...

  @article.comments.build(   # This is the code line 89
    :user_id => @user.id
  )

  if @article.save
    ...
  end
end
```

I get this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `title' for #<Comments:0x00000103abfb90>):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:89:in `create'
```

Probably it happens because the validation run for all `Review` "associated" classes\models and the `Comment` class *doesn't have* the `title` attribute. I think that because if inside the plugin code I comment out the validation method like this

```
module Article
  ...

  included do
    # validates :title,  # Validation
    #   :presence => true
  end

  ...
end
```

I don't get errors anymore.

So, **how can I solve this issue?**

*Note*: I am not expert on creating plugin (this is my first time), so I ask implicitly also if I'm doing a good job for the plugin implementation...

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails/acts_as_gmappable.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including **validates_presence_of :title** in ActiveRecord::Base, and thus every active record model is picking it up.  Instead, you should do:

```
# vendor/plugins/article/lib/acts_as_article.rb
module Article
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   module ClassMethods
    def acts_as_article
      validates :title,  # Add validation method here
        :presence => true
      send :include, InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

So that you only include the validation on ActiveRecord models that expect the validation to go through.  Let me know if this solves your issue.